Why do I get "Dangerous site" warning for my heroku app even after I registered the URL at Google console?
I developed a Shopify app which is hosted on Heroku.
When I access the app URL in order to install the Shopify app, I get the "Dangerous site" warning. I already added the google site verification file to the app which was verified with success, but I still get the "Dangerous site" warning.

Kind regards,
-Louise

google says that the verification can take a few days, you probably have to wait a bit for the verification to be taken into account and propagated.
